# Printing Arabic string correctly in multiple lines

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

Currently I need to process Arabic string (**اسمي مصير الطفل. من أي بلد أنت**) in my project. If the string is displayed in a single line, it is displayed correctly.

[image]

However, when the font size is much bigger, the display (I am using label) is wrong.

[image]

The string is printed starting from the second line. I found that on the .Net framework we could use **drawstring** with **StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft**. However, that is not available in compact framework. So, how could i print Arabic string in multiple lines? Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, the following is incorrect:
*Since WinCE 5 and CompactFramework v 2.0 controls like the Textbox support a RicghtToLeft property (see also http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/rtl-problem.aspx). So you should ensure you are using CF>=2.0 and WinCE 5 base sdk (ie Windows Mobile 6.x).*

Looking at the help for Textbox class, the RightToLeft is marked as NOT AVAILABLE for Compact Framework.

[image]

So, you need to write your own DrawText class that splits the words and positions them from right to left.

The native DrawText API supports the uFormat flag DT_RTLREADING (according to the online help for Windows CE 5 Platform Builder):

DT_RTLREADING 
Layout in right-to-left reading order for bi-directional text when the font selected into the hdc is a Hebrew or Arabic font. The default reading order for all text is left-to-right.

There is also an option DT_WORDBREAK which I would choose for multiline text and a large enough drawing rectangle.

BUT, that gives the following result using two rectangles and two font sizes to force a wordbreak:

[image]

As I can not read that I am not sure, but I assume the wordbreak flag does not work correctly. I assume the second line in the upper part has to start from right too.

Native Code for the above:

```
...
#define ARABIC_TEXT L"اسمي مصير الطفل. من أي بلد أنت"
#define MulDiv(a,b,c)       (((a)*(b))/(c))
...
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
int wmId, wmEvent;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;
RECT rect;
LOGFONT lf;
HFONT hFontNew, hFontOld;
...
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        // TODO: Add any drawing code here...
        // Clear out the lf structure to use when creating the font.
        memset(&lf, 0, sizeof(LOGFONT));
        wsprintf(lf.lfFaceName,L"Arial Unicode MS");

        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);

        hFontNew = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
        hFontOld = (HFONT) SelectObject(hdc, hFontNew);
        rect.bottom=rect.bottom/2;
        lf.lfHeight=-MulDiv(16, GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
        if(DrawText(hdc, ARABIC_TEXT, -1, &rect, DT_RTLREADING | DT_WORDBREAK)==0){
            DEBUGMSG(1, (L"DrawText failed with %i\n", GetLastError()));
        }

        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
        lf.lfHeight=-MulDiv(10, GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
        hFontNew = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
        hFontOld = (HFONT) SelectObject(hdc, hFontNew);
        rect.top=rect.bottom/2;
        if(DrawText(hdc, ARABIC_TEXT, -1, &rect, DT_RTLREADING | DT_WORDBREAK)==0){
            DEBUGMSG(1, (L"DrawText failed with %i\n", GetLastError()));
        }

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        SelectObject(hdc, hFontOld);
        DeleteObject(hFontNew);

        break;
```

Comment: I am using compactframework 3.5 with Wince 6.0. However, I can't seem to find any righttoleft property.

Comment: @josef Perhaps your output just needs a `DT_RIGHT`, right? Also I think the characters appear separated because your WinCE is not built with full arabic script support. +1 though, this is, as far as I know, the only way to display arabic text on WinCE.

Comment: DT_RIGHT might be a fault, as it aligns to right but we want Right-To-Left (RTL) reading. There is no 'built with full arabic' support, there is only Unicode, and that is default with WinCE. One issue is to have a ttf with full arabic support. On the other side: I do not know which platform builder options are needed, except RTL and Unicode, to get a 'full arabic built' of a Windows CE OS image. BTW: editing ARABIC_TEXT in VS was a challenge, as VS recognized the RTL language and behaves strange with BACKSPACE and END and POS1. Nice experience.

Answer (score 1):

The following form is an example of calling `DrawText` (see josef's answer) from C#:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        Menu = null;
        DrawText(e.Graphics, "اسمي مصير الطفل. من أي بلد أنت", Font, ClientRectangle);
    }

    private void DrawText(Graphics g, string text, Font font, Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        IntPtr dc = g.GetHdc();
        RECT rect = (RECT)rectangle;
        IntPtr hFont = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr previousFont = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            hFont = font.ToHfont();
            previousFont = SelectObject(dc, hFont);
            DrawText(dc, text, text.Length, ref rect, DrawTextFlags.RightToLeft | DrawTextFlags.Right | DrawTextFlags.WordBreak);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (previousFont != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                SelectObject(dc, previousFont);
            }
            if (hFont != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                DeleteObject(hFont);
            }

            g.ReleaseHdc(dc);
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct RECT
    {
        internal int Left;
        internal int Top;
        internal int Right;
        internal int Bottom;

        public static explicit operator RECT(Rectangle rect)
        {
            return new RECT()
            {
                Left = rect.Left,
                Top = rect.Top,
                Right = rect.Right,
                Bottom = rect.Bottom
            };
        }
    }
    [DllImport("coredll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern int DrawText(IntPtr hdc, string lpStr, int nCount, ref RECT lpRect, DrawTextFlags flags);
    [DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "DeleteObject")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool DeleteObject([In] IntPtr hObject);
    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr hgdiobj);
    [Flags]
    public enum DrawTextFlags : uint
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Use default values.
        /// </summary>
        None = 0x00000000,

        /// <summary>
        /// Justifies the text to the top of the rectangle.
        /// </summary>
        Top = 0x00000000,

        /// <summary>
        /// Aligns text to the left.
        /// </summary>
        Left = 0x00000000,

        /// <summary>
        /// Centers text horizontally in the rectangle.
        /// </summary>
        Center = 0x00000001,

        /// <summary>
        /// Aligns text to the right.
        /// </summary>
        Right = 0x00000002,

        /// <summary>
        /// Centers text vertically. This value is used only with the SingleLine value.
        /// </summary>
        VerticalCenter = 0x00000004,

        /// <summary>
        /// Justifies the text to the bottom of the rectangle. This value is used only with the 
        /// SingleLine value.
        /// </summary>
        Bottom = 0x00000008,

        /// <summary>
        /// Breaks words. Lines are automatically broken between words if a word would extend past the 
        /// edge of the rectangle specified by the lpRect parameter. A carriage return-line feed sequence 
        /// also breaks the line. If this is not specified, output is on one line.
        /// </summary>
        WordBreak = 0x00000010,

        /// <summary>
        /// Displays text on a single line only. Carriage returns and line feeds do not break the line.
        /// </summary>
        SingleLine = 0x00000020,

        /// <summary>
        /// Expands tab characters. The default number of characters per tab is eight. 
        /// </summary>
        ExpandTabs = 0x00000040,

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets tab stops. Bits 15-8 (high-order byte of the low-order word) of the uFormat parameter 
        /// specify the number of characters for each tab. The default number of characters per tab is 
        /// eight. 
        /// </summary>
        Tabstop = 0x00000080,

        /// <summary>
        /// Draws without clipping. 
        /// </summary>
        NoClip = 0x00000100,

        /// <summary>
        /// Includes the font external leading in line height. Normally, external leading is not included 
        /// in the height of a line of text.
        /// </summary>
        ExternalLeading = 0x00000200,

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines the width and height of the rectangle. If there are multiple lines of text, DrawText 
        /// uses the width of the rectangle pointed to by the lpRect parameter and extends the base of the 
        /// rectangle to bound the last line of text. If the largest word is wider than the rectangle, the 
        /// width is expanded. If the text is less than the width of the rectangle, the width is reduced. 
        /// If there is only one line of text, DrawText modifies the right side of the rectangle so that it 
        /// bounds the last character in the line. In either case, DrawText returns the height of the 
        /// formatted text but does not draw the text.
        /// </summary>
        CalcRect = 0x00000400,

        /// <summary>
        /// Turns off processing of prefix characters. Normally, DrawText interprets the mnemonic-prefix 
        /// character & as a directive to underscore the character that follows, and the mnemonic-prefix 
        /// characters && as a directive to print a single &. By specifying DT_NOPREFIX, this processing 
        /// is turned off. 
        /// </summary>
        NoPrefix = 0x00000800,

        /// <summary>
        /// Uses the system font to calculate text metrics.
        /// </summary>
        Internal = 0x00001000,

        /// <summary>
        /// Duplicates the text-displaying characteristics of a multiline edit control. Specifically, 
        /// the average character width is calculated in the same manner as for an edit control, and 
        /// the function does not display a partially visible last line.
        /// </summary>
        EditControl = 0x00002000,

        /// <summary>
        /// For displayed text, if the end of a string does not fit in the rectangle, it is truncated 
        /// and ellipses are added. If a word that is not at the end of the string goes beyond the 
        /// limits of the rectangle, it is truncated without ellipses.
        /// </summary>
        EndEllipsis = 0x00008000,

        /// <summary>
        /// Layout in right-to-left reading order for bidirectional text when the font selected into the 
        /// hdc is a Hebrew or Arabic font. The default reading order for all text is left-to-right.
        /// </summary>
        RightToLeft = 0x00020000,

        /// <summary>
        /// Truncates any word that does not fit in the rectangle and adds ellipses. 
        /// </summary>
        WordEllipsis = 0x00040000
    }
}
```

(As you can see I've ignored the return values of each native method)

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to take a look at this, was busy these days. The method you suggested didn't work as well, if the sentence is printed on more than one line, it will still start at the second line and ends on the first line.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no solid solution to this issue, so I created a temporary workaround. I am assuming that my Label size is fixed, and if my string size is larger than the width of my Label, I will split it into two. The method I use to split the string is to find a splitting point (currently I am doing it at 0.2 of the total string length).

```
private void processArabic(string arabicString)
{
   string[] stringArray = new string[2];

   double index = 0.8 * arabicString.Length;
   index = Math.Ceiling(index);
   int Index = (int)index;

   for (int i = Index; i != 0; i--)
   {
       if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(arabicString, i))
       {
          stringArray[1] = arabicString.Substring(0, Index + 1);
          stringArray[0] = arabicString.Substring(Index + 1, arabicString.Length - (Index + 1));
          break;
       }
   }

        label1.Text = stringArray[0];
        label1.Text += "\n";
        label1.Text += stringArray[1];
}
```

Although Arabic string is printed from right to left, index is still counted from left to right. The above snippet is rather rigid, and only apply if you want to split the string into two. I am sure there are lot of ways to improve the above code, any comment/suggestion is welcome.